# Seeking song with passionate noises to sample

Tags: soul, sample

I am using GarageBand to make a beatbox version of "There are a Few of My Favorite Things".  Beatbox loops in Garageband are fine, but very masculine.  Garageband does not offer comparable more feminine loops.

I would like some more feminine vocal stylings to add some yin to this yang.  I would like to sample passionate moans, grunts, squeals and such noises.  Garageband has vocal loops done by women but they are more G rated than what I am looking for.  I would prefer to sample from R&B songs or rap songs off Spotify or YouTube, not movies.  But I do not know a wide enough variety of those songs to know where to look.

I would like suggestions for songs that have good sounds of that sort I can sample.

Answer (score 2):

The first two that come to mind for me are:

1) "Love to Love You Baby" by Donna Summer

2) "French Kiss" by L'il Louis

Or are these going too far the other way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a project for your own personal enjoyment --if you're sampling for a commercial project, you'll need to either get all your samples cleared or make sure they are 100% in the public domain.  That's been a very expensive lesson for any number of artists.

I would try the Divinyls "I Touch Myself" or Nathaniel Merriweather's "Lovage" album (try the "Sex" or "Book of the Month" tracks). You might also try Madonna's "Now I'm Following You" (in the breakdown section about halfway through the remixed version).